# KDE Install fails on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, kde

When I run this command

```
sudo tasksel install kubuntu-desktop
```

My terminal gives following line and exit kde install although I have xserver-xorg already installed

```
xserver-xorg                    install
```

How can I install KDE desktop on my ubuntu 18.04. Currently I have gnome desktop.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```